# How to call one or two or both checked boxes and a text input

Tags: javascript, forms, variables, call

I know this is a very basic question, but I am completely new to JavaScript, so I'm desperate. I've poured over how to solve this problem, but I can't figure it out. I need to call the first title or second title or both and the name. How do I do this?  Thanks!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ack(){
var name = document.forms[0].elements[0];
var nameValue = name.value;
var title1 = document.forms[0].elements[1];
var title1Value = title1.value;
var title2 = document.forms[0].elements[2];
var title2Value = title2.value;
alert("Thank you for ordering " +title1Value +title2Value +nameValue);
}
</script>

<form>
<h3>Now Available!</h3> <h4>Happy Traveling 2: More Layouts for the Travel Scrapbooker</h4><br/><br/>
<h3>Also available:</h3> <h4>Happy Traveling: Layouts for the Travel Scrapbooker</h4><br/><br/>
<h4>Order today!</h4><br/><br/>
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name"/><br/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="title1" value="Happy Traveling"/>Happy Traveling<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="title2" value="Happy Traveling 2"/>Happy Traveling 2<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="ack();"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:
1 Use `document.getElementById("your id")` to get page element. It's more efficient and readable. So your code chould be modified to:

```
var name = document.getElementById("name");
```

2 The value of title1 always return "Happy Traveling", nomatter it's checked or not. You should check if it's checked. You can use the "checked" property.

```
var title1 = document.getElementById("title1");
var title1Value = "";
if(title1.checked){
    title1Value = title1.value;
}
```

3 Before you submit a form, you should check if the name is empty.
4 For more information about javascript/html, check [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/) for more details.
Hope it's helpful.

Modified code:

```
function ack(){
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    var nameValue = name.value;
    var title1 = document.getElementById("title1");
    var title1Value = "";
    if(title1.checked){
        title1Value = title1.value;
    }
    var title2 = document.getElementById("title2");
    var title2Value = "";
    if(title2.checked){
        title2Value = title2.value;
    }
    alert("Thank you for ordering " +title1Value +title2Value +nameValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:

Form controls must have a name to be successful, ID attributes are optional and usually not necessary or useful. Form controls are made available as named properties of the form using their name property. So don't use a control name that will conflict with a default property of the form (like "name" or "submit").

Lastly, don't put a click listener on the submit button since users can submit the form by means other than clicking on the button. Give the listener to the form's submit handler, this also means the `ack` function can cancel submit if it wants by returning `false`.

Consider:

```
<form id="orderForm" onsubmit="return ack();"> 
  <input type="text" name="personName"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="title1" value="Happy Traveling">Happy Traveling<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="title2" value="Happy Traveling 2">Happy Traveling 2<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function ack() {
  var form = document.forms[0]; // or use getElementById
  var name = form.personName.value;
  var title1 = form.title1.checked? form.title1.value : '';
  var title2 = form.title2.checked? form.title2.value : '';

  alert('Thank you ' + name + ' for ordering:\n\n' + title1 + '\n' + title2);
}

</script>
```